# Saving embedded .pdf not as .pdf file

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to download a embedded pdf from the chrome browser with below code, however the file is being stored on my C:\ drive as a the following file: `C:\TEST_A_15.pdf.crdownload`.

```
def download_pdf(lnk):

    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    download_folder = "C:\\"

    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False,
                                     "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
           "download.default_directory": download_folder,
           "download.extensions_to_open": ""}

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)

    print("Downloading file from link: {}".format(lnk))

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
    driver.get(lnk)
    filename = lnk.split("=")[3]
    print("File: {}".format(filename))

    print("Status: Download Complete.")
    print("Folder: {}".format(download_folder))

    driver.close()
```

If I adjust the line for `filename` to what's below, then I get the `C:\TEST_A_15.pdf` file desired on my harddrive without the `.crdownload` at the end. But then I get a `IndexError: list index out of range` which is logical because the `"="` is not be found in position 4.

```
    filename = lnk.split("=")[4]
```

The URL used (I changed the hostname and name of pdf file so URL don't work):
`https://testing.nl/getpdf.asp?id=ORsP5UqX6IikuikcGiLD&unique=adda3b24-f9ca-4007-898a-caed5309c140&filename=TEST_A_15.pdf`

Even more strange when I use a network drive together with the `filename = lnk.split("=")[3]` then the file will be stored as a .tmp file i.e.: `2498d715-84aa-4e81-8037-264bb0211b4b.tmp` and when I use the incorrect code (`filename = lnk.split("=")[4]`) it gives the `IndexError` but saves the file correctly as .pdf file on the network drive.

Comment: Your somewhat convoluted question boils down to parsing download URLs with `split("=")`. Please [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, the problem was that the `webdriver` closed before the entire pdf was downloaded resulting in `.tmp` or `.crdownload` files. So I built in a `sleep` before closing the driver.